# Using an article between "after" and a "noun"

Tags: articles

Could you please clarify for me do we supposed to put an article after the word ***before*** or ***after***, when it's preceding a ***noun***?

An example:

> It will be done after *(a)* request from appropriate employee.
>
> We will go jogging before *(a)* breakfast.

Comment: It's not the role of the preposition to dictate whether there should be an article in front of a noun. Whether there is an article in front of a noun depends completely on the noun itself.

Comment: I thought so too but I was confused by the articles on Cambridge Dictionary site: there are examples without articles before *noun* after these *before/after*. So I thought maybe there are some exceptions.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/linking-words-and-expressions/before

Comment: **We will go jogging before breakfast.** — *breakfast* generally doesn't take an indefinite article. When you're talking about the practice of eating food in the morning, it's always used an uncountable noun. The preposition *before* has little to do with *breakfast* being an uncountable noun.

Comment: But in collocations such as "on request" or "upon request" the articles are omitted even though there are nothing but prepositions and nouns. So I am perplexed.

Comment: I guess that in English adverbial phrases and certain set expressions tend not to include articles as part of their structure. As far as I know, there are no general rules that can help you tell exactly in which situations a particular noun requires an article in front of it. You sort of have to learn that on a case by case basis. Article usage in English is a complex topic.

Comment: So am I right saying "after a request" but "on request"?

Comment: Yes, *after a request* and *after the request* are both grammatical. *On request* is a set phrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the reference is not to a particular request but to a *condition*, the statement is a generality and the reference is  to requests in general, hence no article:

> We will send you more information **upon request**.

Zero-article is one way to enlist the noun in a generality.

The way to refer to "appropriate employee" or "authorized employee" in general terms is to use the indefinite article:

> We will send more information upon request by **an authorized employee**.

The reference is not to a particular employee but to *any* employee having the necessary authorization.

Another way is to use the plural but that could be ambiguous here:

> We will send more information upon request by **authorized employees**.

It might seem as if a co-requestor was required. Here it is a little less ambiguous:

> **Authorized employees** may request further information.

Given the structure of your example sentence, the singular **an authorized employee** is the best way to express the general condition or requirement.